# Hide app icon on navigation drawer home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

In my Nexus 5 (without physical buttons) it's alright, my action bar is as follow:

[image]

**This is what I want for all devices.**

Instead, in devices with physical buttons, this happens:

[image]

What should I do to force to show always the home button **without the app icon**?

The code used to setup the ActionBar in my Activity (in the onCreate() method) is:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

If I change:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

with:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

then I obtain that in all devices (both with or without physical buttons):

[image]

but I don't want the app icon near the icon with 3 lines!

Answer (score 1):

Set custom style for ActionBar like this:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> <!-- Hide logo from the action bar -->
</style>
```

thin set this style in application theme following way:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

where:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Good luck!