# Custom logo in ActionBar alongside drawer toggle

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't seem to add a logo to the ActionBar no matter what I try.

Here is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.feedview);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    title = drawerTitle = getTitle();

    drawerItemsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    //add the items to the navigation drawer here
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavigationDrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername(), ""));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_social_add, drawerItemsList[1], ""));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_reqs, drawerItemsList[2], ""));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_settings_power_black_24dp, drawerItemsList[3], ""));

    //set adapter
    adapter = new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, navDrawerItems);
    drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_wide);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    generateListView();

 swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.white, R.color.black, R.color.gray);
    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    generateListView();
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 2500);
        }
    });

}
```

and my custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="OrangeActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/OrangeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="OrangeActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
</style>
```

My logo won't show. I've tried setting a logo item in my theme and setting `displayOptions` to `useLogo|showHome` but that simply hides whatever should be in the logo/title space across ALL activities. I've tried adding an `android:logo` attribute in the manifest to no avail. Nothing shows up, and I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with my drawer toggle but I can't diagnose the issue properly. Any idea why my logo isn't showing up in the Action Bar and what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Edit: I am targeting SDK versions 11+. Also, I've added what my ActionBar currently looks like. It displays the label rather than the logo, and if I remove the label it shows the class name:

[image: My ActionBar]

Comment: So your targetSDKVersion is less than 21?

Comment: @Xcihnegn Sorry I've added those details. Yes I'm targeting 11+.

Comment: Add `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: I tried that with no success. I've edited the code to reflect my changes. I tried putting it after `setLogo` and before.

Comment: Look this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323955/hide-app-icon-on-navigation-drawer-home-button)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have logo here because you are using Navigation Drawer.  There is recommended design for it and ActionBarDrawerToggle implements it. It would be strange to have app logo alongside with navigation icon. 
To have application icon in action bar just use application pattern without NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Toolbar provided in the support library (along with AppCompatActivity or AppCompatDelegate)? It's available from support library V7 and you can set your ActionBar to be the toolbar using `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`. You Activity will need to inherit from the AppCompat.NoActionBar style too.

You can then have an icon next to the NavigationDrawerToggle like this:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/home_toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="56dip" android:background="@color/white">

  <ImageView android:layout_width="56dip" android:layout_height="56dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Although you need to override the setting of the title because this will appear to the left of the icon by default. You can just add a textview to the toolbar and set it as any other TextView, and your ImageView can contain pretty much anything.

If you can't use AppCompatActivity, the newest version of the support library introduced an interface AppCompatCallback and an abstract class AppCompatDelegate last week that you can use with normal activities. I haven't actually tried it yet but it's meant to allow normal activities to have support features. This gives example usage: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3

Obviously this approach has its downsides, but it is possible to achieve this way!

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking to add an icon, but rather a full logo.

Comment: You can put anything in the ImageView, not necessarily just an icon. Toolbar lets you add pretty much anything

Comment: I see. I'll give this a shot, although I recall for some reason not being able to use AppCompat. I think it requires my activities to extend it but I need to extend something else for my backend set up. I'll try again. Is there an alternative way to set it up?

Comment: They introduced an interface AppCompatCallback and an abstract class AppCompatDelegate last week that you can use on normal activities. I haven't actually tried it yet but it's meant to allow normal activities to have support features. This gives example usage: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3

Comment: Andy, this was so helpful. I couldn't use the support library because I was already extending a class, but this new interface was so helpful! Please edit your comments into the answer so I can accept it!